# How to pass variables between 2 procedures in VB.NET (Web Application)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am basically creating textboxes dynamically for adding a test to the database. The number of textboxes to be created was passed as a query string from the web page before. Here is the code:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim NoOfQuestions As Integer = Request.QueryString("NoOfQuestions")
    Dim txtboxQ(NoOfQuestions - 1) As TextBox
    Dim txtboxA(NoOfQuestions - 1) As TextBox

    For i = 1 To NoOfQuestions
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<span>Question " & i & "</span>"))
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(txtboxQ(i - 1))
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<span>Correct Answer</span>"))
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(txtboxA(i - 1))
        Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))
    Next

End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'Some SQL stuff
    Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx")
End Sub
```

I am trying to pass both the textbox arrays that were declared in Page_Load to the other sub btnSubmit_Click. I tried to pass it as parameter like this but it didn't seem to work:

```vb
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs, ByRef txtboxQ() As TextBox, ByRef txtboxA As TextBox) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'Some SQL stuff
    Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx")
End Sub
```

Quiet lost here, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a list of text boxes on page level

```
Public textQ = New List(Of TextBox)
Public textA = New List(Of TextBox)
```

Change your code to following

```
For i = 1 To NoOfQuestions
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<span>Question " & i & "</span>"))
     Dim txtboxq = New TextBox()
     txtboxq.ID = "txtq_" & i
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(txtboxq)
     textQ.Add(txtboxq)
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<span>Correct Answer</span>"))
     Dim txtboxa = New TextBox()
     txtboxa.ID = "txta_" & i
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(txtboxa)
     textA.Add(txtboxa)
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(txtboxa)
     Placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))
Next
```

then access the values in the list for any purpose, may be print values on submit or whatever..

eg:

```
    For Each tb As TextBox In Me.textQ
        Me.label1.Text = Me.label1.Text & tb.Text.Trim()
    Next
```

Comment: I never knew about lists and I understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the textboxes content as output parameters in the querystring, as you did with your input parameter NoOfQuestions

```
Dim sQuery As String
For i = 1 To NoOfQuestions
    sQuery &= "Question" & i & " & txtboxQ(i - 1).Text & "Answer" & i & "=" & txtboxA(i - 1).Text
Next i
Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx?" & sQuery)
```

And the parse the query string in the Page Load event of HomePage.aspx. You can also pass the values as session variables

```
Session("Question1") = txtboxQ(i - 1).Text
...
```

And then

```
Dim question1 As String = Session("Question1")
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why would you want to pass the variables like that when you can declare the variables in page level and access it from any method/function. Any special requirement?

what you are trying to do here is unclear as well.

Comment: The problem with using a global variable is that, the textbox array is created upon information coming from the query string which is requested when the page loads in the sub Page_Load. This is basically a learning system and this is the web form for adding a test by the admin to the database with the correct answers. So the system asks the number of questions to be added, in a dialog (in a previous web page) which passes this as query string and redirects to this web form. As the page loads, the textboxes are created dynamically and when submitted (btnSubmit.Click) it is sent to the database.

Comment: got it! added a new answer check if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable inside you class, and place it below your class code. And if you want to use it, you just call that global variable.